# Circle Event in Fortune's Algorithm for Voronoi Diagram

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

In the Fortune's algorithm for 2D Voronoi Diagram, while adding circle events, we check whether the tangent to the circle will be in future of the current position of sweepline.
I am trying to visualize a situation in which it will **not** be.

There are two scenarios when circle events can be added:

1. Post a site event.
2. Post a deletion of parabola.

I guess that for circle event post a site event the tangent to the circle will always be in future (or present). Correct me if I am wrong here.

I need help visualizing a scenario in which the the tangent to the circle is in the 'past' of sweepline. Any reference which gives such a scenario will be equally useful.